# in textfile to array, value comparison fails, although apparent exact match, php

Tags: php, arrays, string, if-statement

I read a .txt file with file(), so it turns each newline into an array item

```
<?php
  $f = file('artistsitem.txt');
```

output of print_r of the resulting array

```
Array ( [0] => caption: > [1] => «  Pot, Pot, Pot », video [2] => view, Arkansas Modern, 2010 )
```

I then loop the array and compare it with a string, but it fails, no matter if using equal or identical operator

```
  foreach($f as $k => $v){  
    if($v === ' caption: > '){
        echo 'found <br />';
    }
  }
```

In the original text file, the string at $f[0] appears as such, with two spaces before and a newline after

[image]

Exploding the string at $f[0] gives:

```
Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] => c [3] => a [4] => p [5] => t [6] => i [7] => o [8] => n [9] => : [10] => [11] => > [12] => )
```

A var_dump of the array, gives, for that line:

```
[0]=> string(13) " caption: > "
```

Although the ammount of spaces confuses me, no matter the combination of spaces I use before or after the comparison string, it fails to match.

Same thing happens with $f[2] with value '-  ' although exploding it gives:

```
Array ( [0] => - [1] => [2] => )
```

and var_dump

```
[22]=> string(3) "- "
```

Attempting to manually reproduce the array and running the comparison, works.

I am puzzled at what is going on.

Thanks

Comment: Be a lot easier with actual code, not output. Obviously the values *don't* match.  Look at the hex or hash them or something if you've doubts.

Comment: @ficuscr Thanks. I do not fully understand your comment. The array comes from '$f = file('textfile.txt')' which is a textfile I cannot post, both for length and privacy. How do I look at the hex ? thanks

Comment: It may be that what you are seeing as a space may be some other character in the text file.  You might try using strpos($v,'caption') inside your loop to do an initial check and if a match occurs, loop through $v itself printing out the ord() of each character.  An actual space character should return a value of 32.

Comment: Hint: [bin2hex()](http://php.net/bin2hex)

Comment: @JaumeMal see [`bin2hex `](http://php.net/manual/en/function.bin2hex.php).  Compare string piece by piece.  You can't just look at the screen and know they match or don't.

Comment: @cmerriman Using ord() gives me the last char is a line feed, so /n. I am unsure on how to specify a line feed in the string I use for comparison. help? thank you

Comment: Ah, I see, I can use 'string' . "\n"

Comment: You might also look at using trim() before the comparison.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using ord() or bin2hex() it is possible to check the ascii or hex codes of each character in $v to see why it is not matching.

```
foreach($f as $v){  
    if(strpos($v,'caption')){
        $vv = str_split($v);
        foreach($vv as $c){
            echo ord($c) . '<br />';
        }
    }
}
```

In my case this showed the first two chars where 32 (space) but the last char was 10 (line feed or \n)

```
ord: 32
ord: 32
ord: 99
ord: 97
ord: 112
ord: 116
ord: 105
ord: 111
ord: 110
ord: 58
ord: 32
ord: 62
ord: 10
```

I then updated my comparison adding a line feed as such:

```
if($v == '  caption: >' . "\n"){
    echo 'found <br />';
}
```

Note double quotes are necessary for \n to be interpreted.

Alternatively I could use trim() to remove spaces and newline from both extremes of $v before running the comparison.